# Using equation to find value of $1/x - 1/y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

$$\left(\frac{48}{10}\right)^x=\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^y=1000$$

What is the value of $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}$?
I have already used that when $48$ divided by $10$ then it becomes $4.8$ and when $8$ divided by $10$ then it becomes $0.8$ by getting $10^x$ and $10^y$ to make it simpler but I cannot proceed further.

Answer (score 6):

HINT :

$$4.8=1000^{\frac 1x},\ \ \ 0.8=1000^{\frac 1y}$$
So, $$1000^{\frac 1x-\frac 1y}=\frac{1000^{1/x}}{1000^{1/y}}=\frac{4.8}{0.8}$$

Answer (score 2):

From $4.8^x = 1000$ we get $4.8 = 1000^{1/x}$ and similarly for the $y$ term we get $0.8 = 1000^{1/y}$ by taking the $x$ and $y$-root of both sides respectively. Hence we get $$\frac{4.8}{0.8} = \frac{1000^{1/x}}{1000^{1/y}}$$

This yields $$6 = 1000^{1/x - 1/y}$$ so $$\bbox[10px, border: solid red 2px]{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} = \log_{1000} 6}$$ by applying the $1000$-base logarithm of both sides of the equation.

Comment: I think base 10 is more conventional.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac{48}{10}\right)^x=1000 \Longleftrightarrow $$
$$\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)^x=1000 \Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{\log_{10}(1000)}{\log_{10}\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)}$$

---

$$\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^x=1000 \Longleftrightarrow $$
$$\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x=1000 \Longleftrightarrow y=\frac{\log_{10}(1000)}{\log_{10}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}$$

So:

$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\Longrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{\frac{\log_{10}(1000)}{\log_{10}\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)}}-\frac{1}{\frac{\log_{10}(1000)}{\log_{10}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}}=$$

$$\frac{\log_{10}\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)}{\log_{10}(1000)}-\frac{\log_{10}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}{\log_{10}(1000)}=$$

$$\frac{\log_{10}\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)}{3}-\frac{\log_{10}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}{3}=$$

$$\frac{\log_{10}\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)-\log_{10}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}{3}=$$

$$\frac{\log_{10}(6)}{3}$$

Comment: by applying hints of you all i get two different result. which one is exact answer 0.25 or 35.36???

Comment: What you've asked, mine is the exact answer. Try it out put my $x$ and $y$ in your formula and you see that it becomes: $1000=1000=1000$ and that is equal. So fitting $x$ and $y$ in, in $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}$ gives you my answer!

Comment: I do not think that this is correct (but I may be wrong). To me  $$\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)^x=1000 \Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{\log_{10}(1000)}{\log_{10}\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)}$$Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you was totaly right, I've changed it!

Comment: Now, I agree ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Haha, me too! Thanks for your remark! Cheers buddy

Answer (score 0):

Let us make it more general considering $$a^x=b^y=c$$ Take logarithms (using any base) $$x \log(a)=y\log(b)=\log(c)$$ So $$x \log(a)=\log(c)\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{\log(c)}{\log(a)}\Longleftrightarrow \frac 1x=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(c)}$$  $$y \log(b)=\log(c)\Longleftrightarrow y=\frac{\log(c)}{\log(b)}\Longleftrightarrow \frac 1y=\frac{\log(b)}{\log(c)}$$   $$\frac 1x-\frac 1y=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(c)}-\frac{\log(b)}{\log(c)}=\frac{\log(a)-\log(b)}{\log(c)}=\frac{\log(\frac ab)}{\log(c)}$$ which simplifies if you use $\log_c(.)$ as Zain Patel proposed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac{48}{10}\right)^x=\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^y=1000$$

$$48^x = 10^{x+3} \; \; \; \& \; \; \; 8^y = 10^{y+3}$$

$$x+3  =  x \log {48} \Rightarrow \; \; \; 1 + \frac{3}{x} = \log {48}$$

$$y+3 = y \log {8} \Rightarrow \; \; \; 1 + \frac{3}{y} = \log {8}$$

$$3 \times (\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}) = \log {48} - \log {8} = \frac{\log_2 {48}}{3}$$

$$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} = \frac{\log_2 {48}}{9} \approx 0.62055$$